# Postgres - Vaccum Full

Tags: postgresql

I am facing a problem and I cannot find a way to solve it.
I have a PostgreSQL embedded on a Raspberry. To prevent it from writing to the card several times, I put all PostgreSQL running in RAM and perform a procedure to save it to the SD once a day.
This PostgreSQL receives data from different devices and writes the data in a table.
A Python process runs every 10 seconds. This process performs a function that selects data from a table and writes the data to a remote database via DBLink. After, this same process deletes the rows from the local table.

Every 1 hour I have a process that runs a Vaccum Full to free up the space occupied by the database and ensure that Raspberry does not run out of RAM.
What I have faced is that apparently the Vaccum Full is getting stuck for some reason and for this reason the database does not decrease in size, crashing the Raspbery.

Anyone have any idea what could be ?

Thanks!

Comment: Best guess is you have a open transaction that has changed tuples and/or is holding locks. ```VACUMM FULL``` needs exclusive locks on any table it works on. Also it will not clean up tuples that are part of an open transaction as it does not know if they will be needed should the transaction roll back. [pg_locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/view-pg-locks.html) and [pg_stat_activity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) are useful for exploring this.

Comment: Have you checked the postgres log?